# customizing a spinner for a different look

Tags: android, user-interface

I've got xml code for spinner and a textview like this:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/EventOptions"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryComplement"
        style="@style/loginEditTextStyle"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/emailField2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="TextView"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryComplement"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryComplementSemiTransp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:theme="@style/loginEditTextStyle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8" />
```

And the current result is:
[image]

But, I'd like to customize the spinner for a different look. As you can see the `textView`'s  text doesn't align with the spinner's text. So, I'd like to get rid of the arrow or atleast align the text with the textView. Something like:

[image]
Also, I'd like every item in the list from the dropdown in the spinner to have the textColor as white with underlines if possible.

Answer (score 0):

***Output:***

[image]

Place this `spinner_item.xml` inside your `layout` folder which defines your `Spinner`'s every `item`'s `textColor`, `textSize`, `paddings` etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Place this `activity_main.xml` inside your `layout` folder which is the main layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="#F81616"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/divider1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/divider1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/spinner"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/spinner"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then in the `MainActivity.java` file add the following code:

***Kotlin:***

```
val spinnerArray = arrayOf("Spinner", "Category-1", "Category-2", "Category-3")
val spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerArray) 
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
spinner.adapter = spinnerArrayAdapter
```

***Java:***

```
Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
String[] spinnerArray = {"Spinner", "Category-1", "Category-2", "Category-3"};
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerArray);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: why is the spinner text leftAligned even though gravity is centered